# How to hide a column in pry / rails output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pry-rails

I have an image blob written to a field in the db, but I don't want to see that output in a console when I view the user object.

I don't need the output changed or modified for the functioning of the application this is JUST for debugging / developing with the console.  I did attempt some of the serialization concepts but they aren't helpful for these purposes.  I also looked into filter_parameters which only are helpful for logging and not pry console output.

I am using the pry-rails gem for the rails console, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit late to the party, but in current versions of ActiveRecord, the cleanest solution would be to overwrite `attribute_for_inspect`, e.g.

```rb
def attribute_for_inspect(attr_name)
  return 'SKIPPED' if attr_name == :blob

  super
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the `inspect` method for the object.
Have a look at the default implementation of [`inspect`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L497%20%60inspect%60) - it uses all the object's attributes. You'll have to change that to include only the columns/attributes you want to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `select` to do that

```
User.select(User.attribute_names - ['avatar', 'permalink']).last
```

if you use this frequently, i'd suggest you declare a scope for your `User` class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :pry_scope, ->{ select(User.attribute_names - ['avatar', 'permalink']) }
  ...
end
```

then use it on your console:

```
> User.pry_scope.last
```